# How do I perform u-substitution on this problem?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, rational-functions, substitution

I am having trouble with this problem:
$$\int {\frac{3x + 5}{5x^2 - 4x - 1}} dx$$

I can't seem to find a ***u*** where the ***du*** exists in the numerator so that it will cancel.

If I choose:
$$u = 5x^2 - 4x - 1$$

Then:
$$du = 10x - 4 dx$$

I'm fundamentally not clear on how to rewrite my problem so that I can perform u-substitution here.

Comment: Try to use partial fractions instead of a substitution. By the way, writing $\mathrm du=10x-4$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ah, had tried that before but I couldn't get it to work. Going back I realized that my mistake was not factoring the denominator properly.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the $$dx$$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach when confronted with integrals of rational functions (with a complicated polynomial in the numerator), is to "split" the rational function into two fractions for which we know the integral.

In this case, we can factor the numerator into:
$$
5x^2-4x-1=(5x+1)(x-1)
$$
The idea now is to try to find $A$ and $B$ such that:
$$
\frac{3x+5}{5x^2-4x-1}=\frac{A}{5x+1}+\frac{B}{x-1}
$$
Because given these $A$ and $B$ we know that:
$$
\int \frac{3x+5}{5x^2-4x-1}\;dx=\int \frac{A}{5x+1}+\frac{B}{x-1}
\;dx=\frac{A}{5}\log(5x+1)+B\log(x-1)
$$

When we add the fractions on the right we find that:
$$
3x+5=A(x-1)+B(5x+1)=(A+5B)x+(B-A)
$$
From which it follows that:
$$
A+5B=3 \qquad\text{and}\qquad B-A=5
$$
We can solve this to find:
$$
A=-\frac{11}{3},\qquad B=\frac{4}{3}
$$
Therefore the solution is:
$$
\int \frac{3x+5}{5x^2-4x-1}\;dx=-\frac{11}{15}\log(5x+1)+\frac{4}{3}\log(x-1)
$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $$ \frac {-11}{15}log(5x+1)$$

Comment: Yeah the problem I had was in recognizing: $$5x^2 - 4x - 1 = (5x + 1)(x - 1)$$ so I tried to do u-substitution instead, which was the wrong move.

Comment: @dydxx Yes, you are very right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Kiernan When you have trouble finding a proper factorization, try to find a root of the polynomial. You can do this using the standard Quadratic Formula, or in this case we can easily see that $1$ is a root because $5-4-1=0$. Then we know that we can write $5x^2-4x-1=(cx+d)(x-1)$ for some $c,d$ which you can easily determine.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, one should let $$M\frac{d}{dx}(5x^2-4x-1)+N=3x+5$$ 
$$M(10x-4)+N=3x+5$$
by comparing the corresponding coefficients on both the sides, $M=\frac{3}{10}$ & $M=\frac{31}{5}$, hence

$$\int \frac{3x+5}{5x^2-4x-1}\ dx$$
$$=\int \frac{\frac{3}{10}(10x-4)+\frac{31}{5}}{5x^2-4x-1}\ dx$$
$$=\frac{3}{10}\int \frac{(10x-4)dx}{5x^2-4x-1}+\frac{31}{5}\int \frac{1}{5x^2-4x-1}\ dx$$$$=\frac{3}{10}\int \frac{(10x-4)dx}{5x^2-4x-1}+\frac{31}{5}\int \frac{1}{5\left(\left(x-\frac{2}{5}\right)^2-\frac{9}{25}\right)}\ dx$$

$$=\frac{3}{10}\int \frac{(10x-4)dx}{5x^2-4x-1}+\frac{31}{25}\int \frac{1}{\left(x-\frac{2}{5}\right)^2-\frac{9}{25}}\ dx$$
Now, for the first integral, substitute $u=5x^2-4x-1\implies (10x-4) dx=du$ & for the second integral substitute $t=x-\frac{2}{5}\implies dx=dt$, 
$$=\frac{3}{10}\int \frac{du}{u}+\frac{31}{25}\int \frac{1}{t^2-\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^2}\ dt$$
$$=\frac{3}{10}\ln|u|+\frac{31}{25}\cdot \frac{1}{2\cdot \frac{3}{5}}\ln\left|\frac{t-\frac{3}{5}}{t+\frac{3}{5}}\right|+C$$
$$=\frac{3}{10}\ln|5x^2-4x-1|+\frac{31}{30}\ln\left|\frac{5x-5}{5x+1}\right|+C$$